# Distinguishing the levels of a factor variable in R

Tags: r, dataset

Let's say my data set contains three columns: id (identification), case (character), and value(numeric). This is my dataset:

```
tdata <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), case=c("a","b","c","c","a","b","c","c","a","b","c","c","a","b","c","c"), value=c(1,34,56,23,546,34,67,23,65,23,65,23,87,34,321,56))

tdata
   id case value
1   1    a     1
2   1    b    34
3   1    c    56
4   1    c    23
5   2    a   546
6   2    b    34
7   2    c    67
8   2    c    23
9   3    a    65
10  3    b    23
11  3    c    65
12  3    c    23
13  4    a    87
14  4    b    34
15  4    c   321
16  4    c    56
```

If you notice, for each ID, we have two c's. How can I rename them c1 and c2? (I need to distinguish between them
for further analysis).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
within(tdata, case <- ave(as.character(case), id, FUN=make.unique))
```

Comment: I like it a lot. I think to give what he expects is should be done within each `id` set. See your edit. Now it's perfect.

Comment: You could also wrap it in `sub` to remove the `.`

Comment: @RichardScriven, that's true. From OP's final remark, though, I'm guessing this may not be important.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, but this is the R tag on SO. Don't you know that we have to present things *exactly* according to the OP's specs to get any respect around here? :-)

Comment: Oh!  I just noticed that this great function has a `sep` arg as well.  Even better

Comment: @RichardScriven you're right, but unfortunately with `ave` I'd have to make it an anonymous function to use this argument.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew Plourde!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that rather than replacing the values in the "case" column, you just add a secondary "ID" column. This is easily done with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package.

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(tdata, c("id", "case"))[]
#     id case value .id
#  1:  1    a     1   1
#  2:  1    b    34   1
#  3:  1    c    56   1
#  4:  1    c    23   2
#  5:  2    a   546   1
#  6:  2    b    34   1
#  7:  2    c    67   1
#  8:  2    c    23   2
#  9:  3    a    65   1
# 10:  3    b    23   1
# 11:  3    c    65   1
# 12:  3    c    23   2
# 13:  4    a    87   1
# 14:  4    b    34   1
# 15:  4    c   321   1
# 16:  4    c    56   2
```

The `[]` may or may not be required depending on which version of "data.table" you have installed.

If you *really* did want to collapse those columns, you could also do:

```
getanID(tdata, c("id", "case"))[, case := paste0(case, .id)][, .id := NULL][]
#     id case value
#  1:  1   a1     1
#  2:  1   b1    34
#  3:  1   c1    56
#  4:  1   c2    23
#  5:  2   a1   546
#  6:  2   b1    34
#  7:  2   c1    67
#  8:  2   c2    23
#  9:  3   a1    65
# 10:  3   b1    23
# 11:  3   c1    65
# 12:  3   c2    23
# 13:  4   a1    87
# 14:  4   b1    34
# 15:  4   c1   321
# 16:  4   c2    56
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this slightly modified approach:

```
library(dplyr)

tdata %>% group_by(id, case) %>% mutate(caseNo = paste0(case, row_number())) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% select(-case)

#Source: local data frame [16 x 3]
#
#   id value caseNo
#1   1     1     a1
#2   1    34     b1
#3   1    56     c1
#4   1    23     c2
#5   2   546     a1
#6   2    34     b1
#7   2    67     c1
#8   2    23     c2
#9   3    65     a1
#10  3    23     b1
#11  3    65     c1
#12  3    23     c2
#13  4    87     a1
#14  4    34     b1
#15  4   321     c1
#16  4    56     c2
```

Comment: I had a similar approach. `mutate(tdata, case = as.character(case)) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(case = ifelse(case == "c", paste(case,row_number(), sep = "."), case))`In this way, you can leave a and b as they are, and make distinctions between two cs.

Comment: @jazzurro, but that wouldn't result in c1 and c2 but, for id 1, in c3 and c4, right?

Comment: Yep.Either you assign numbers to all or numbers to cs only.